# knockout get old value of the text box

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm using mapping plugin.  I have an on 'blur' event whenever someone takes away focus from a text box. I would like to know if the old value is different from new value. This works correct for "enter" key. For some reason whenever I change the value and press enter I get this console output FIRST time; 'oldValue | newValue'. However this is not the case when 'blur' fires. I get 'newValue | newValue'

How come?. How can i get the new and old values on blur?

HTML:

```html
<input class="percent-text" data-bind="text: Percent, value: Percent, event: { keypress: $root.percentUpdate, blur: $root.percentUpdate }" type="number" min="1" max="100" oninput="maxlength(this)" maxlength="3" />
```

Knockout:

```js
    self.percentUpdate = function (data, event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.type == 'blur') {
            var $target = $(event.currentTarget);
            console.log(data.Percent() + " | " + event.target.value); 
        }
        return true;
    };
```

Comment: Are you basically trying to get a notification whenever Percent is updated?

Comment: No. I want the actual old value and the new value after I the blur evet fires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with your approach (I had a succesful testcase), but as @AnotherDev mentioned it's simpler to use the built-in tools. Inside the `subscribe` function you have access to the value *before* or *after* it is changed, and act upon it accordingly. If you want to still be able to retrieve previous values afterwards, you could easily do this with **caching** the preceding value, or even all preceding values (in an array). Note that the only reason `cachedPercent(s)` are observable in the fiddle is to update the viewModel JSON; in a real app I would use plain array/ number (and ev. in private variable).

Test it in the fiddle below; wth this approach the `ENTER` key function only needs a manual call to `valueHasMutated` to notify the subscribe function.

```js
function App(percent) {
  var self = this;
  this.cachedPercent = ko.observable(percent || 0);
  this.cachedPercents = ko.observableArray([percent || 0]);
  this.PercentRaw = ko.observable(percent || 0);
  // Percent stores an integer, and is ratelimited to make sure
  // that the value isn't stored 1000x every time the user increments
  this.Percent = ko.computed(function() { 
    return parseInt(self.PercentRaw()); 
  }).extend({rateLimit: 500});
  this.storePercents = this.Percent.subscribe(function(oldVal) {
    // delete this if clause if you want to manually check somewhere else
    // because this tells JS not to store any value when similar to the previous one
    if (self.cachedPercent() !== oldVal) {
      self.cachedPercent(self.Percent());
      self.cachedPercents.splice(0, 0, self.Percent());
    }
  }, null, 'beforeChange');
}
ko.applyBindings(new App(50));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="value: PercentRaw, 
                  event: {keydown: function(d, e) { if (e.keyCode === 13) PercentRaw.valueHasMutated(); } " type="number" min="1" max="100" maxlength="3" class="percent-text" />

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Knockout updates the value on blur and the value is probably getting updated before your blur event. I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but I would look into using .subscribe and .subscribe with beforeChange.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

For example

```
data.Percent.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert(newValue)
});
```

And

```
data.Percent.subscribe(function(oldValue) {
        alert(oldValue)
    }, null, "beforeChange");
```